# wordpress search result and permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have a page that search's posts from specific category. when the permalink is in post id format it works well, but when I change it to post name format it returns no result :

when the permalink format is post id :

- search page url :`localhost/wordpress/?pageid=12`
- result page url :`localhost/wordpress/?s=123`
- it works well but When I use postname format :

  ```
  search page url: localhost/wordpress/verifycertificates/?s=123
  ```
- result page url : `localhost/wordpress/verifycertificates/?s=123`

it loads the "404 page" and the result not found.

the problem is here :

```
result page url :localhost/wordpress/?s=123
result page url: localhost/wordpress/verifycertificates/?s=123
```